# InputStream to Channel for Selector

Tags: java, nio

I've searched high and low, but can't find a definitive, up-to-date answer to my question about NIO.

Is there any way to convert from an `InputStream` to a `Channel` that I can use with a `Selector`? It seems like `Channels.newChannel()` is the only way to do the conversion but doesn't provide an instance of `AbstractSelectableChannel`, which is really what I need.

More specifically, I would like to read from the `stdout` and `stderr` streams of a subprocess without creating one thread per stream, and it seems this is the only way to do it in pure Java. Since these streams are using pipes to pass I/O back and forth I'm surprised `.newChannel` doesn't return a `Pipe.SourceChannel`, which is a subclass of `AbstractSelectableChannel`.

I'm using Java 7 (although if new functionality is available in 8 I would still be happy for an answer).

**EDIT:** I also tried casting the results of `.newChannel()` to a selectable channel to no avail - it is not a selectable channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do what you're asking, but you don't need a thread per stream. Just merge the streams with the API provided for the purpose, and read the output in the current thread.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't merge the streams because my third-party subprocess' `stderr` is interspersed randomly into `stdout` (they aren't separated by newlines, as one would hope).

Comment: You can do this without an extra thread, but it requires a polling loop to capture the `stdout` and `stderr` streams to different places (e.g. `StringBuilder`s) separately. Using `select` would be way better, but it doesn't look like it's possible to do that. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I can redirect output of subprocesses to files and analyze the output later. You can use something like the code below, but it has some drawbacks and some code should be added. Instead of the lock some concurrent collection can be used.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class InputPrcocessSelector {

    final private Collection<Process> registeredProcesses = new HashSet<>();
    final private Lock registeredProcessesLock = new ReentrantLock();

    final private LinkedBlockingQueue<Process> readyProcesses = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    final private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    final private static TimeUnit DEFAULT_TIME_UNIT = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;
    final private static int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 100;

    final private int timeOut;
    final private TimeUnit timeUnit;

    public InputPrcocessSelector() {
        this(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, DEFAULT_TIME_UNIT);
    }

    public InputPrcocessSelector(int timeOut, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        this.timeOut = timeOut;
        this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
        this.executorService.submit(new SelectorTask());
    }

    public boolean register(Process process) {
        try {
            registeredProcessesLock.lock();
            return registeredProcesses.add(process);
        } finally {
            registeredProcessesLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean unregister(Process process) {
        try {
            registeredProcessesLock.lock();
            return registeredProcesses.remove(process);
        } finally {
            registeredProcessesLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public Collection<Process> select() throws InterruptedException {
        HashSet<Process> selectedInputs = new HashSet<>();

        Process firstProcess = readyProcesses.take();
        selectedInputs.add(firstProcess);

        Process nextProcess = null;
        while ((nextProcess = readyProcesses.poll()) != null) {
            selectedInputs.add(nextProcess);
        }

        return selectedInputs;
    }

    private class SelectorTask implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    registeredProcessesLock.lock();

                    Iterator<Process> it = registeredProcesses.iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Process p = it.next();
                        try {
                            int available = p.getInputStream().available();
                            if (available > 0)
                                readyProcesses.add(p);
                            if (p.isAlive() == false) {
                                System.err.println("Not alive");
                                it.remove();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }

                } finally {
                    registeredProcessesLock.unlock();
                }

                try {
                    timeUnit.sleep(timeOut);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```